# declaring xml as constant in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anybody help to assign this xml as constant string in javascript. How to assign     this xml as constant without any changes?

```
   "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">
      " +
      "<wp:Tile>
        " +
        "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
        "<wp:Count>" + TextBoxCount.Text + "</wp:Count>" +
        "<wp:Title>" + TextBoxTitle.Text + "</wp:Title>" +
        "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
        "<wp:BackTitle>" + TextBoxBackTitle.Text + "</wp:BackTitle>" +
        "<wp:BackContent>" + TextBoxBackContent.Text + "</wp:BackContent>" +
        "
      </wp:Tile> " +
      "
    </wp:Notification>";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need it to be constant? Javascript does not really have that. What do you want to achieve or avoid?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have a constant modifier.

Closest you could do is define it with [`defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and set `writable` to `false`.

Also, your string...

```
  "<wp:Tile>
    " +
```

...won't work as the parser currently doesn't support multiline strings. You'll need to break it up with `" + "` or use the escape character as the last character.